# Code working a week ago, now I am getting an error without changing anything in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a small web scraper that was working fine a couple of weeks ago, but now gives me an error without me having changed any part of my code. My code is listed below for reference:

```
address = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h3[@class = "street"]')
price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class = "price"]')
details = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class = "details"]')

num_page_items = len(details)
with open('results.csv', 'a') as f:
    for x in range(num_page_items):
        f.write(address[x].text + " , " + price[x].text.replace(",", "") + "," + details[x].text + "\n")
```

I am using selenium (I omitted the import and setup since that part of the code works fine) and when I run my code I get the following error:

```
line 25, in <module>
    f.write(address[x].text + " , " + price[x].text.replace(",", "") + "," + details[x].text + "\n")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I did some researching but when I print `len(details)` I get 24, which indicates that there are values in the details variable. Since the range is defined, and I get a result for the length of the list, why would I get an out of range error?

Comment: Either `address` or `price` does not have as many items as `details`.

Comment: If the code stops working without any changes, it means that the data you're dealing with changed. You just have to redo your analysis of the web page you're scraping, which most likely had a recent redesign. That's what happens when you web-scrape instead of using an API.

Comment: What has the length of `details` to do with incexing into `address`? if details > address - then you get out of range errors. Print all lenght - especially of those you index into - see [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes that the length of each of the arrays is the same, but that's not guaranteed. Like others have said, reconsider your implementation if the design of the site has changed.

Alternatively, if you want to stop throwing errors, you could look into the built in zip library. https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

This will group together your arrays into an array of tuples, creating n tuples where n is the length of your smallest array. Consider though that if the site has changed its design, the meaningfulness of the newly created zip may not be valid.